# Unable to connect from apache to tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, connectivity

Application is not working and failing with below reason. Could someone please help on this.

connectivity apache -> tomcat

**Error logs**

> [Mon Sep 10 03:00:07.123556 2018] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 12345]
>   (104)Connection reset by peer: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't
>   receive header

**ssl_error_log**

> [Mon Sep 10 03:00:07.123456 2018] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 12345]
>   [client 10.10.34.901:56789] AH00992: ajp_read_header:
>   ajp_ilink_receive failed,

**Tomcat configuration**

```
<Connector port="8009" 
           protocol="AJP/1.3" 
           maxConnections="256" 
           keepAliveTimeout="30000" 
           redirectPort="8443">
```

**Apache configuration**

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/ timeout=600
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProxyPass` needs [an additional argument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), e.g.

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ ...
```

Comment: yes  i tried like below still its not working.

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse /  ajp://localhost:8009/ timeout=600

<Proxy "ajp://localhost">
  ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</Proxy>

Comment: I have the same problem , Did solve the problem? Do you came to a solution?